# Janrain SSO check_login token_uri not called

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, janrain

I'm currently implementing janrain single-sign-on on several site.
I check if the user is already logged with this code:

```
 JANRAIN.SSO.ENGAGE.check_login({
        sso_server: 'my_sso_server_uri',
        logout_uri: 'my_logout_uri',
        xd_receiver: 'my_xd_uri',
        token_uri: 'my_token_uri'
    });
```

If I understand the janrain doc, if a user is already logged, it should be redirected to the token_uri.
But this redirection seems to work in one case only:

- start : user is not logged on any site
- the log into site A
- the user open the login page on site B and he's automalitaly redirected to the token_uri
- close all browser windows
- open the login page on site B : the user is not redirected to the token_uri

but in the browser console, I can see that the user is correctly logged on all sites.

can you help me to solved this issue, how to get the user always be redirected to the token_uri.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding appears to be correct, the check_login() method should see if the user has logged in on any other federated site and, if so, redirect the user to the token_uri defined locally. If you are experiencing that this only works if the user explicitly navigates to the login page on site B, perhaps the check_login() code is only on that page? In order for this to work the code block must appear on every page.